# How to have a two-part cron job that compare status updates

Tags: php, mysql, cron

**UPDATE:** **I opted to write the results of the first query to a file with a second cron job to read and compare the results of a second query. I am still interested in learning if what I was trying to accomplish below can be done; currently it works with short `sleep()`s but the 30 minute is too much.**

My goal is to have a script that runs every hour with the following steps:

1. query MySQL for records with a status of `F` within the last hour.
2. push those records to an array and format them into a string variable.
3. wait 30 minutes.
4. query MySQL again with the string variable.
5. if there is **no change** (status is still `F`) send an email, ignoring those that have a changed status.

When I've tested this in a local environment it works however when it's live it fails. I'm not sure if it's a cron issue or that I'm using `sleep()` when there might be a better suited method.

My functions:

```
function getRecordsWhereF($dbConnect){
  $query = "SELECT record FROM table WHERE date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND status NOT LIKE '%P%'}";

  $recordsF_query = mysqli_query($dbConnect, ($query)) or die(mysqli_error($dbConnect));
  $recordsF = array();

  while($recordF = mysqli_fetch_array($recordsF_query)){
    $recordsF[] = $recordF;
  }

  if($recordsF){ die(); };

  return $recordsF;
}

function setupChecks($recordsF){
  $recordsA = "";
  $i = 0;

  foreach($recordsF as $record){
    $i = $i + 1;
    $key = $record['key']; // the id changes so we have to compare using the key
    $check .= "key LIKE '%{key}%'";

    if($i < count($recordsF)) {
      $check .= "OR ";
    }
  }

  $check = "AND $check";

  return $check;
}

function queryForChanges($dbConnect, $check){
  // Wait 30 minutes to allow for changes
  sleep(1800); 
  $query = "SELECT key FROM table WHERE status NOT LIKE '%P%' $check}";

  // query, set arrays

  return $recordsStillF;
} // after this it sends an email with the record information.
```

In my local environment I'll receive get an email like so:

```
Records F:
id: 1, key 1, recordA
id: 2, key 2, recordB
id: 3, key 3, recordC
id: 4, key 4, recordD
id: 5, key 5, recordF

Records still F:
id: 6, key 1, recordA
id: 7, key 3, recordC
id: 8, key 5, recordF
```

However once the cron job is set to run on the hour, every hour, it doesn't work and there are no errors to be had. Could `sleep()` be a poor choice here and causing issues with the cron job (there are several cron jobs running at any given time) or is there something else I should tweak?

Your guidance is much appreciated and I'm happy to update the question as needed.

Comment: for one thing, you're mixing different mysql apis here. `mysql_fetch_array` won't work with an `mysqli_` connection, and if that's all this is, then there's a dupe for it. Edit: Now I see that that was edited. Wil lthis be an "edit on the fly" type of thing?

Comment: and a possible variable scoping.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner you're right, that was a typo in the question. In my script it reads `mysqli_fetch_array`. I've corrected that.

Comment: Don't use `sleep`. Just configure a 2nd `cron` instead of the sleep to test for those that did not change and send e-mails

Comment: @DarkBee would I then save the records from the first query to a json file? Or would I nest another cron job within that 3rd function? (I don't handle the cron jobs so I'm not sure what can/should be done.)

Comment: Why don't just add a flag column, update that to `1` instead of creating a new array. Then u'r new `cron` would be a select of those with the flag fielld set to `1`. Check whether their statusses changed, send e-mail and all flags back to `0`?

Comment: @DarkBee I want to make sure I understand what you're saying: why don't I create a column in the table with a value or `0` or `1` to show changes? This wouldn't work because the same record doesn't get updated with the change, a new record is made entirely with the different status. After having thought about it I have some alterations to make to the logic (currently it returns all of the records both the `F` record and the new one when it should only show the new), but I'm still unsure how to handle a 2 part cron job where there's a break of 30 minutes between functions.